# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object in re

Tags: python, time, utc, python-re

I want to grab 'Asia/Tel_Aviv' and 'Asia/Jeruslam' from this huge list, here is the full code:

```
import pytz
alltmzn=pytz.alltimezones
print(alltmzn)
t=alltmzn[234:332]
for i in re.findall("^J|Tel",t):
     print(i)
```

error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most 
recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-fe8a33f8999a> in <module>
       1 t=alltmzn[234:332]
 ----> 2 for i in re.findall("^J|Tel",t):
       3     print(i)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\re.py in findall(pattern, string, flags)
239 
240     Empty matches are included in the result."""
 --> 241     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
242 
243 def finditer(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`
```

Comment: and please don't press the bottom: "This is not useful" it isn't helping me and please be open-minded to me.

Comment: `t` is a list. `findall` expects a string.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: can you write it on answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t` is a list, while `findall` expects a string.

You can rewrite it this way:

```
for tz in t:
  if re.search(pattern, tz):
    print(tz)
```

Note that your pattern will match strings *starting* with "Tel" or "Jel" (not Jer, and not including "Asia/" before), which is probably not what you want.

Comment: in your case that's `"^J|Tel"`, as in your question.